# an array of self-defined swift object can't be converted to objective-c type

Tags: objective-c, swift, mixed-code

A newbie to swift

I'm doing a mixed-language **(Swift & Objective-C)** program, and encounter an error when trying to **import Swift into Objective-C**

here is my code

```
@objc public enum ItemType: Int {
  case left, right
}
public class MyClass {
  @objc var items: [ItemType] = []
}
```

Here is the error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkPbi.png)

It seems that there's something wrong about the `ItemType` but I do see the definition of `ItemType` in my `-swift.h` file

Could any one give me a hint?

Comment: Have you did bridging?

Comment: yes, both swift to objc and objc to swift, if i didn't get you wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swift and Objective-c enums is very different in their nature. Old Objective-c enum is very little subset of modern Swift enum. Currently compiler doesn't know how to use Swift's enum from Objective-c code so they can't be @objc type. MyClass also can't be @objc type while it contain swift's enum.